# Scraping Wikipedia tables with Python selectively

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I have troubles sorting a wiki table and hope someone who has done it before can give me advice.
From the List_of_current_heads_of_state_and_government I need countries (works with the code below) and then only the first mention of Head of state + their names. I am not sure how to isolate the first mention as they all come in one cell. And my attempt to pull their names gives me this error: `IndexError: list index out of range`. Will appreciate your help!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_heads_of_state_and_government"
website_url = requests.get(wiki).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')

my_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable plainrowheaders'})
#print(my_table)

states = []
titles = []
names = []
for row in my_table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    state_cell = row.find_all('a')[0]  
    states.append(state_cell.text)
print(states)
for row in my_table.find_all('td'):
    title_cell = row.find_all('a')[0]
    titles.append(title_cell.text)
print(titles)
for row in my_table.find_all('td'):
    name_cell = row.find_all('a')[1]
    names.append(name_cell.text)
print(names)
```

Desirable output would be a pandas df:

```
State | Title | Name |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I could understand your question then the following should get you there:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_heads_of_state_and_government"

res = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'lxml')
for items in soup.find('table', class_='wikitable').find_all('tr')[1::1]:
    data = items.find_all(['th','td'])
    try:
        country = data[0].a.text
        title = data[1].a.text
        name = data[1].a.find_next_sibling().text
    except IndexError:pass
    print("{}|{}|{}".format(country,title,name))
```

Output:

```
Afghanistan|President|Ashraf Ghani
Albania|President|Ilir Meta
Algeria|President|Abdelaziz Bouteflika
Andorra|Episcopal Co-Prince|Joan Enric Vives Sicília
Angola|President|João Lourenço
Antigua and Barbuda|Queen|Elizabeth II
Argentina|President|Mauricio Macri
```

And so on ----

Comment: Or you can try like this as well `print(country,title,name,sep=" | ")`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

I found a super easy and short way to do this, by importing the `wikipedia` python module and then using pandas' `read_html` to put it into a dataframe.

From there you can apply any amount of analysis you wish.

```
import pandas as pd
import wikipedia as wp
html = wp.page("List_of_video_games_considered_the_best").html().encode("UTF-8")
try: 
    df = pd.read_html(html)[1]  # Try 2nd table first as most pages contain contents table first
except IndexError:
    df = pd.read_html(html)[0]
print(df.to_string())
```

OR if you would like to call it from the command line:

Simply call by `python yourfile.py -p Wikipedia_Page_Article_Here`

```
import pandas as pd
import argparse
import wikipedia as wp
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", "--wiki_page", help="Give a wiki page to get table", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
html = wp.page(args.wiki_page).html().encode("UTF-8")
try: 
    df = pd.read_html(html)[1]  # Try 2nd table first as most pages contain contents table first
except IndexError:
    df = pd.read_html(html)[0]
print(df.to_string())
```

Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

it is not perfect but it almost works like this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_heads_of_state_and_government"
website_url = requests.get(wiki).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')

my_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable plainrowheaders'})
#print(my_table)

states = []
titles = []
names = []
""" for row in my_table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    state_cell = row.find_all('a')[0]  
    states.append(state_cell.text)
print(states)
for row in my_table.find_all('td'):
    title_cell = row.find_all('a')[0]
    titles.append(title_cell.text)
print(titles) """
for row in my_table.find_all('td'):
    try:
        names.append(row.find_all('a')[1].text)
    except IndexError:
        names.append(row.find_all('a')[0].text)

print(names)
```

There is just one mistake in this names list so far i can see. The table is a bit difficult due to the exceptions you must write. For example there are names they aren't a link and then the code catches just the first link it finds in that row. But you will just need to write some more if clauses for such cases. At least i would do it so.