# How to read wikipedia table of 2018 in film using python pandas and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was attempting to find the movies of 2018 January to March of 2018 from [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_in_film) using pandas read html.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_in_film"

tables = pd.read_html(link)

jan_march = tables[5].iloc[1:]

jan_march.columns = ['Opening1','Opening2','Title','Studio','Cast','Genre','Country','Ref']

jan_march.head()
```

There is some error in reading the columns. If anybody has already scraped some
wikipedia tables may be they can help me solving the problem.

Thanks a lot.

Related links:
[Scraping Wikipedia tables with Python selectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355577/scraping-wikipedia-tables-with-python-selectively)
https://roche.io/2016/05/scrape-wikipedia-with-python
[Scraping paginated web table with python pandas & beautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119584/scraping-paginated-web-table-with-python-pandas-beautifulsoup)

I am getting this:
[image]

But am expecting:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of how the table is designed it is not as simple as `pd.read_html()` while that is a start you will need to do some manipulation to get it in a desirable formate:

```
import pandas as pd

link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_in_film"

tables = pd.read_html(link,header=0)[5]

# find na values and shift cells right
i = 0
while i < 2:
    row_shift = tables[tables['Unnamed: 7'].isnull()].index
    tables.iloc[row_shift,:] = tables.iloc[row_shift,:].shift(1,axis=1)
    i+=1

# create new column names
tables.columns = ['Month', 'Day', 'Title', 'Studio', 'Cast and crew', 'Genre', 'Country', 'Ref.']

# forward fill values
tables['Month'] = tables['Month'].ffill()
tables['Day'] = tables['Day'].ffill()
```

out:

```
    Month   Day Title   Studio  Cast and crew   Genre   Country Ref.
0   JANUARY 5   Insidious: The Last Key Universal Pictures / Blumhouse Productions  Adam Robitel (director); Leigh Whannell (scree...   Horror, Thriller    US  [33]
1   JANUARY 5   The Strange Ones    Vertical Entertainment  Lauren Wolkstein (director); Christopher Radcl...   Drama   US  [34]
2   JANUARY 5   Stratton    Momentum Pictures   Simon West (director); Duncan Falconer, Warren...   Action, Thriller    IT, UK  [35]
3   JANUARY 10  Sweet Country   Samuel Goldwyn Films    Warwick Thornton (director); David Tranter, St...   Drama   AUS [36]
4   JANUARY 12  The Commuter    Lionsgate / StudioCanal / The Picture Company   Jaume Collet-Serra (director); Byron Willinger...   Action, Crime, Drama, Mystery, Thriller US, UK  [37]
5   JANUARY 12  Proud Mary  Screen Gems Babak Najafi (director); John S. Newman, Chris...   Action, Thriller    US  [38]
6   JANUARY 12  Acts of Violence    Lionsgate Premiere  Brett Donowho (director); Nicolas Aaron Mezzan...   Action, Thriller    US  [39]
   ...
```